# Here in decorator person_lister(f) having function inner(p) which represent people I want to know is it possible to get the same answer without inner?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Here in decorator person_lister(f) having function inner(p) which represent people I want to know is it possible to get the same answer without inner?

```
def person_lister(f):
    def inner(p):
        return [f(i) for i in sorted(p, key=lambda l : l[2])]
    return inner

@person_lister
def name_format(person):
    return ("Mr. " if person[3] == "M" else "Ms. ") + person[0] + " " + person[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    people = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]
    print(*name_format(people), sep='\n')
```

Comment: A decorator to be applied to a function must, generally speaking, return a different function that wraps the function it's being applied to.  A nested `def` is generally the simplest way to implement that.  Why do you feel a need to avoid it?

Comment: without modifying the signatures of the target function and the decorator you can replace `inner` with anything which is callable, from a `lambda` to a `class`... it is only a matter of design

Comment: @jasonharper I am actually new to this concept so I was curious to know that it can be possible or not. btw thanks brother for explaining

Comment: @cards your explanation is very straight forward . thanks buddy